# JNI Object pass from JNI to Java Object parameter

Tags: java, android, object, android-ndk, java-native-interface

JNI File :

```
jObj = lJNIEnv->NewObjectArray(2,lJNIEnv->FindClass("java/lang/String"),0);

jmethodID APIHttp = lJNIEnv->GetMethodID(lClassDeviceAPI, "PassData","(Ljava/lang/Object;)I");
                     if(APIHttp == NULL) {
                       LOGI("CallMethod::   method found");
                       }
                    sent=lJNIEnv->CallIntMethod(appc->lObjDeviceAPI,jObj);
```

**Java :**

```
public int PassData(Object object) {
... 
..

}


Logs: "CallMethod::   method found"
```

Can anybody know what is  object parameter needs to pass when we pass the object from JNI => Java?

**Exception:**

```
  JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallIntMethodV called with pending exception 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError' thrown in unknown throw location
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking, but you could use `ExceptionDescribe` and see if the output helps to find out what is going wrong with `GetMethodID`

Comment: The `GetMethodID()` call seems to match, so my guess would be that `lClassDeviceAPI` is pointing at the wrong class.

Comment: I want to pass Object to Java class. What the GetMethodID ("Ljava/lang/Object") is wrong. So what shall I use instead of that ?@fadden

Comment: What fadden is saying is that probably not the `GetMethodID` is wrong but your parameter `lClassDeviceAPI`. From where do you get that?

Comment: More sweet question . to pass this object what parameter should I include on java side, List <String> , string [] or any things?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in jni.h, CallIntMethod has this signature (uses varargs for the remaining arguments):

```
jint CallIntMethod(jobject obj, jmethodID methodID, ...)
```

So your method ID is the second argument and your array is in the varargs list.  I assume that appc->lObjDeviceAPI is the jobject for your class instance.

```
sent = lJNIEnv->CallIntMethod(appc->lObjDeviceAPI, APIHttp, jObj);
```